# Django query to join records of two tables

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset, django-mssql

I am using django-mssql 1.6.2 package with django 1.7 to get one or several records of tables from sql server 2008. When I call "get" or "filter" as follows, everything is fine but my server program is very slow. Consider the following tables:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
      id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True, null=False)
      address = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
      phone = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

class Parent(models.Model):
      id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True, null=False)
      name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
      contact = models.OneToOneField(Contact)

class Student(models.Model):
      id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True, null=False)
      name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
      parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
```

Assume that we want to print a table in a template like:

```
Student name  |  Parent name  |  Parent phone number
John          |  Jack         |  1111111
Susan         |  Jack         |  1111111
Dan           |  Jack         |  1111111
Jackie        |  Sara         |  2222222
```

I use a code like:

```
    query_results = list()
    parents = Parent.objects.all()
    for any_parent in parents:
        students = Student.objects.filter(parent=any_parent)
        for student in students:
            element = TempObjectForStudent()
            element.student_name = student.name
            element.parent_name = any_parent.name
            element.parent_phone = any_parent.contact.phone
            query_results.append(element)

         if students.__len__() == 0:
            element = TempObjectForStudent()
            element.student_name = 'without any active student'
            element.parent_name = any_parent.name
            element.parent_phone = any_parent.contact.phone
            query_results.append(element)

class TempObjectForStudent():
    student_name = None
    parent_name = None
    parent_phone = None
```

With a template like:

```
{% for row in query_results %}
    <tr><td>{{ row.student_name }}</td><td>{{ row.parent_name }}</td><td>{{ row.parent_phone }}</td></tr>
```

As I mentioned before, the problem is the speed of running lots of queries in this method. How can I use join to deliver all of the table data in just one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you made it a little bit too complicated.

There is no need for TempObjectForStudent. You can get the student instance without that. Simply add a `related_name` to you `Student` model's `parent` field, so you can get reference to the `Parent` object simply using dot notation.

Also please note that Django gives each model the `id` field automaticaly. You can read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#primary-key). So there is no need to create that field explicitly in your models.

Regarding your question, I would do it like this:

```
# models.py
class Parent(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
      contact = models.OneToOneField(Contact)

class Student(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
      parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='students')

# views.py
parents = Parent.objects.all()

# template.html
{% for parent in parents %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {% with parent.students.all as students %}
                {% for student in students %}
                    {{ student.name }}
                {% empty %}
                    'without any active student'
                {% endfor %}
            {% endwith %}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ parent.name }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ parent.contact.phone }}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

### Update:

I came across a `select_related` QuerySet method. I think that this is what you've been searching for! It uses SQL `JOIN` clause and includes all related object's fields in `SELECT` statement. Read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-related). I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks but I don't think it really affects the performance. Could you please give a solution to join  tables too?

Comment: What is the reason you think it doesn't affect the performance? I do not use any additional querys like filtering used in your code, which does affect the performance. Creating a new instances of TempObjectForStudent, assigning it attributes - it's another thing that I do not do in my proposed solution, which might affect your performance. I do not know what do you mean by 'join tables'? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You mentioned the problem is the speed of running queries in your code, but, personally, I do not think that joining the data into one table(you need to use yet another queries to do that) would help you to speed it up. I am not an expert, so I may be wrong, but that is just my own opinion.

Comment: Yes, I could Improve the performance using select_related and prefetch_related @an0o0nym