# Adding data from two models into one table in Django?

Tags: html, django, django-models, html-table, datatables

I'm trying to add data from two models into one table. They are linked via a Foreign Key. I have searched the forum but cannot find a method that works with my data.

At the moment, I can display a single models data in the table but not the other. I'm using MySQL as my database.

My models.py file:

```
class location(models.Model):
    loc_room = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    loc_block = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    loc_shelf = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True, null=True)

class box(models.Model):
    box_contents = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True) 
    project_assigned_to = models.ForeignKey('project', null=True)
    location_id = models.ForeignKey('location', null=True)
```

My views.py file:

```
def all_assets(request):
    box_data = box.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main_app/all_assets.html', { "box_data":box_data 
})
```

My table:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Assets</th>
        <th>Project</th>
        <th>Room</th>
        <th>Block</th>
        <th>Shelf</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for item in box_data %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ item.box_contents }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.project_assigned_to }}</td>
    <td>**Here I need to add data from ROOM**</td>
    <td>**Here I need to add data from BLOCK**</td>
    <td>**Here I need to add data from SHELF**</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

I hope somebody can help me with this. I've been trying out all the solutions on the forum but non work with my data. The closest I got was [Django query to join records of two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38678583/django-query-to-join-records-of-two-tables) But again, I couldn't get it to work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try {{ item.location_id.loc_room }}

Comment: I think you mean {{ item.location_id.loc_room }}! I see what you were trying to say and it worked! Thank you so much, I've been stuck on this for hours!